# Cannot connect to Sphinx through MySQL connection

Tags: .net, mysql, sphinx, mysql-connector

I was trying to connect to a Sphinx search server using its MySQL interface. However, once I tried to connect, the following exception was thrown by the MySQL .NET connector: **Connector/Net no longer supports server versions prior to 5.0**

I can successfully connect to the MySQL interface using the command-line mysql command on the server. How can I use the .NET connector to connect to the Sphinx MySQL interface>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default, Sphinx returns a MySQL version of 2.0.4 and that most recent MySQL .NET connectors require a MySQL version of 5.0+. However, one can make Sphinx return a different MySQL version by modifying the *sphinx.conf* file. Just add the following line to the **searchd** configuration section of the *sphinx.conf* file:

`mysql_version_string = 5.0.37`

Of course, you can use any version you'd like. After the configuration has been edited, do a restart of sphinx:

`searchd --stop

searchd`

Try connecting again and the .NET connector will see a compatible MySQL version returned by Sphinx and everything works!